# Can we say everything is "Data" in Functional Programming?

Tags: function, functional-programming, composition

I'm trying to learn and understand thinking Functionally. What I learned so far gives me the idea below:

> There are 2 sides to Any application, Algorithm and Data, and functional programming lets us beautifully separate them when designing our solution. But on the other hand Algorithms are being written by Functions, and Functions are values in Functional Programming.

Based on this, Functional Programming is about **Composing Data** and not only Functions! Functions are only a specific kind of data.

How much I'm correct? and where do I need to work on my reasoning?

Comment: All programming is about composing data into data structures. But no, I wouldn't say that functions are (just) data. Sure, functions are values and can be passed around, but in contrast to data they are a) executable b) not de-composable (at runtime) c) not serialisable

Comment: In the lambda calculus, everything is a function, even data. In Lisp everything is in principle a list, IIRC. In reality there will usually be some kind of distinction between data and functions.

Comment: @Bergi c) Functions in reality are not serializable but in theory they could be right? Imagine if the running application is aware of the the function body and code and all functions are all pure. We can sending the `code` of the function to a running application, and run them or compose them. b) They don't need to be decomposable, we can look at them as primitive types. a) The only thing I feel makes them special is that they are executable.

Comment: "*Imagine*" - yes, that's possible in [homoiconic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), but rather uncommon. And languages like Java or [Unison](https://www.unison-lang.org) know how to load/send code over the network to execute it remotely. Interpreters are blurring the line. And certainly you may treat code/instructions as data, e.g. in a compiler - but normal applications don't do that, and it's not specific to functional programming either (although manipulating and composing functions is of course easier than imperative code). Otherwise you make good points :-)

Comment: "*The only thing that makes them special is that they are executable.*" - yeah, this probably comes down to the [harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture) of modern computers